# What is the difference between /etc/network/interfaces and /etc/config/network

Tags: networking

I have been using ubuntu for quite sometime now. But just recently started getting interested on the networking side of it (Mainly for work reasons). Just recently I ran into an embedded linux system which uses /etc/config/network in order to configure the interfaces on the system. As far as I know in order to do that you should use the /etc/network/interfaces file instead. Could anyone tell me what is the difference between this two files (if there is any?). Just as an example, the content of the files is:

/etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto eth0
```

/etc/config/network:

```
option proto 'static'
option ipaddr '127.0.0.1'
config interface 'loopback'
option netmask '255.0.0.0'

config interface 'eth0'
option proto 'dhcp'
```

Comment: Your embedded system is using another linux distribution, most likely openwrt or another specialized distribution.

Comment: /etc/config/network is not an Ubuntu file. I vote to close as not about Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

It has a difference:

```
/etc/config/network
```

This configuration file is used by [netifd (Network Interface Daemon)](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/techref/netifd) mostly used in OpenWrt distributions.

```
/etc/network/interfaces
```

This configuration file is used by **ifup (including ifdown and ifquery)** utility.
In other hand, distributions like Ubuntu, Debian use the [NetworkManager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetworkManager)
daemon which manages network interfaces, connections in a flexible way.

If you want to use `ifup` instead of NetworkManager, you should configure NetworkManager not to manage interfaces used in `/etc/network/interfaces`.

Answer (score 0):

`/etc/config/network` is usually used in OpenWRT/LEDE. It is off-topic here.

But networking basics are remain the same - static/dynamic IP, netmask, gateway, inbound/outbound (LAN/WAN) role.

See [*Chapter 4. Networking* of *Ubuntu Server Guide*](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/serverguide.pdf) for Ubuntu-related details.